# How to get rid of the braces and commas returned by Arrays.toString()?

Tags: java, arrays, string, tostring

Consider this code-

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test  {
public static void main(String args[])  {
    int[] arr=new int[5];

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {arr[i]=i;}

    String sarr=Arrays.toString(arr);
    System.out.println(sarr);
}
}
```

The output is-

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to know weather there is a way to get rid of the braces and the commans introduced by toString()?? I want my String to be like this-

```
"01234"
```

Answer (score 5):

Just build the string yourself, with a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int value : arr) {
    builder.append(value);
}
String text = builder.toString();
```

Basically if you don't want the formatting that `Arrays.toString` provides you, I'd avoid using it in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get rid of the characters that you do not want is to not put them in in the first place:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int n : arr) {
    sb.append(n);
}
String sarr = sb.toString();
```

However, if you must remove the punctuation after the fact, you could use `replaceAll`:

```
sarr = sarr.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use fast enumeration and StringBuilder - maybe into a static method taking int[] as argument.

For instance:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(arr.length);
for (int i: arr) {
    sb.append(i);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output:

```
01234
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove all non digit characters:

```
String sarr = Arrays.toString(arr).toString().replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not relying on the toString() representation from Arrays, since it is mostly meant for easier debugging, not for any productive use. If you want the information in a certain structured way, format it that way yourself (e.g. by looping over the array and appending to a StringBuilder).